# Show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\,\left[0,\,\infty\right)\setminus\left\{1\right\}\,$.

Tags: real-analysis

I think this has to do with Dini's theorem, because I notice that $f_n(x)= \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$ is continuous and monotonically converges because of: 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 0$$ and $$f_n(x) \geq f_{n+1}(x)$$
But then question asks for the convergence of a series, so I am not sure how to go about this.

I also tried the Weierstrass M-test with some $p$-series and Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence, but the "every compact subset" just does not seem to fit.

Comment: How does this series converge for $x=1$?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [THIS](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321528/for-which-intervals-on-bbb-r-is-sum-n-1-infty-fracxn1x2n-unifo?rq=1).

Comment: It should be $[0,\infty)\backslash\{1\}$. The other question has some similarities, but my question is specifically about the every compact subset part (which leads to uniform convergence).

Comment: Take any number $x_0<1$.  Then on any closed set $[0,x_0]$, it is easy to show UC.  Then, take any numbers $1<x_1<x_2<\infty$, it is easy to show UC on $[x_1,x_2]$.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, however, I am a bit not sure if this includes every compact subsets. For example, if I take the cantor set between $[x_1, x_2]$, would I still be able to show UC?

Comment: Yes.  UC on every point of the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ is guaranteed.  So, take any subset thereof and you have UC at each point of the subset obviously.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was reassuring. I was worried about something very obvious.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  UC is a very powerful convergence and guarantees that one can interchange certain operations (e.g., limits with integrals).  - Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x_0<1$.  Then on any compact set $[0,x_0]$, we have

$$\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\le x_0^n$$

Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_0^n=\frac{1}{1-x_0}<\infty$, then by the [Wierestrass M Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test#Statement), the series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,x_0]$ for all $x_0<1$.

Now, take any two numbers $1<x_1<x_2<\infty$.  On any compact set $[x_1,x_2]$, we have

$$\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\le\frac{1}{x_n}\le \frac{1}{x_1^n}$$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x_1^n}=\frac{x_1}{x_1-1}<\infty$, then by the [Wierestrass M Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test#Statement), the series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges uniformly .